# pyspark - kafka stream - out of memory

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, out-of-memory

I'm trying to test kafka streaming with broker version 0.10 with this code. It's just a simple code to print the content of a topic. Not a big deal yet! But, for some reason memory is not enough(10GB of RAM in a VM)! The code:

```
# coding: utf-8

"""
kafka-test-003.py: test with broker 0.10(new Spark Stream API)

How to run this script?

spark-submit --jars jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar,jars/kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar kafka-test-003.py



"""


import pyspark 
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession,Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils


# starting spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Kakfa-test").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

# getting streaming context
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2) # batching duration: each 2 seconds

broker = "kafka.some.address:9092"
topic = "my.topic"

### Streaming

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", broker) \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .option("subscribe", topic) \
  .load() \
  .select(col('key').cast("string"),col('value').cast("string"))

query = df \
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("console") \
  .start()

### End Streaming

query.awaitTermination()
```

Running spark submit:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --driver-memory 5G --executor-memory 5G --jars jars/kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar,jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar kafka-test-003.py
```

Unfortunately, the result is:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I'm assuming that Kafka should bring a little portions of data per time exactly to avoid this problem, right? So, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

spark memory management is a complex process. The optimal solution depends not only on your data and type of operations and the system behavior 
can you retry the following spark command:

> spark-submit --master local[*] --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 2G
>   --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 8  --jars jars/kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar,jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar
>   kafka-test-003.py

Can you adjust the above memory parameters as per the following link by tuning your performance? [Using spark-submit, what is the behavior of the --total-executor-cores option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031214/using-spark-submit-what-is-the-behavior-of-the-total-executor-cores-option)